# Convergence of sum involving $\log$ - comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

WolframAlpha tells me that the sum $$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right)-1\right)$$ converges, and that this can be shown using the comparison test. I cannot see what sum it is comparing to - can anyone assist? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\left(\frac1x+\frac12\right)\log(1+x)-1&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$then$$g\left(\frac1r\right)=\left(r+\frac12\right)\log\left(1+\frac1r\right)-1.$$On the other hand,$$g(x)=\frac{x^2}{12}-\frac{x^3}{12}+\cdots$$and therefore$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)}{x^2}=\frac1{12}.$$But then$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{\left(r+\frac12\right)\log\left(1+\frac1r\right)-1}{\frac1{r^2}}=\frac1{12}$$too. So, since the series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac1{r^2}$ converges, your series converges.